fix error " With n_samples=0, test_size=0.1 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters."
I wrote a program in python and I want to implement NLP by BERT algorithm.I have a dataset and the below code but when I ran the program at colab I encounter below error
    import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import hazm
from hazm import Lemmatizer
from cleantext import clean
import nltk
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
import os
import re
import json
import copy
import collections

from transformers import BertConfig, BertTokenizer
from transformers import TFBertModel, TFBertForSequenceClassification
from transformers import glue_convert_examples_to_features

import tensorflow as tf
MAX_LEN = 128
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 16
VALID_BATCH_SIZE = 16
TEST_BATCH_SIZE = 16

EPOCHS = 3
EEVERY_EPOCH = 1000
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-5
CLIP = 0.0

MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH = 'HooshvareLab/bert-fa-base-uncased'
OUTPUT_PATH = '/content/bert-fa-base-uncased-sentiment-taaghceh/pytorch_model.bin'

os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(OUTPUT_PATH), exist_ok=True)
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
data = pd.read_csv('Education.csv',header=None)
data.drop(0,inplace=True,axis=1)
data
data[1].replace('ترس','ترس ',inplace=True)
data[1].unique()
with open('stopwords.txt') as stopwords_file:
   stopwords = stopwords_file.readlines()
nltk_stopwords = [str(line).replace('\n', '') for line in stopwords]
data['comment_len_by_words'] = data[1].apply(lambda t: len(hazm.word_tokenize(t)))
data
min_max_len = data["comment_len_by_words"].min(), data["comment_len_by_words"].max()
print(f'Min: {min_max_len[0]} \tMax: {min_max_len[1]}')
def data_gl_than(data, less_than=100.0, greater_than=0.0, col='comment_len_by_words'):
    data_length = data[col].values

    data_glt = sum([1 for length in data_length if greater_than < length <= less_than])

    data_glt_rate = (data_glt / len(data_length)) * 100

    print(f'Texts with word length of greater than {greater_than} and less than {less_than} includes {data_glt_rate:.2f}% of the whole!')
data_gl_than(data, 256, 3)

# remove comments with the length of fewer than three words
minlim, maxlim = 3, 256

data['comment_len_by_words'] = data['comment_len_by_words'].apply(lambda len_t: len_t if minlim < len_t <= maxlim else None)
data = data.dropna(subset=['comment_len_by_words'])
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    return cleantext

def cleaning(text):
    text = text.strip()
    
    # regular cleaning
    text = clean(text,fix_unicode=True,to_ascii=False,lower=True,no_line_breaks=True,no_urls=True,no_emails=True,no_phone_numbers=True,
        no_numbers=False,no_digits=False,no_currency_symbols=True,no_punct=False,replace_with_url="",
        replace_with_email="",
        replace_with_phone_number="",
        replace_with_number="",
        replace_with_digit="0",
        replace_with_currency_symbol="",
    )

    # cleaning htmls
    text = cleanhtml(text)
    
    # normalizing
    normalizer = hazm.Normalizer()
    text = normalizer.normalize(text)
    # removing wierd patterns
    wierd_pattern = re.compile("["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
        u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937"
        u'\U00010000-\U0010ffff'
        u"\u200d"
        u"\u2640-\u2642"
        u"\u2600-\u2B55"
        u"\u23cf"
        u"\u23e9"
        u"\u231a"
        u"\u3030"
        u"\ufe0f"
        u"\u2069"
        u"\u2066"
        # u"\u200c"
        u"\u2068"
        u"\u2067"
        "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    
    text = wierd_pattern.sub(r'', text)
    
    # removing extra spaces, hashtags
    text = re.sub("#", "", text)
    text = re.sub("\s+", " ", text)
    
    return text
    data
data['cleaned_comment'] = data[1].apply(cleaning)

# # calculate the length of comments based on their words
data['cleaned_comment_len_by_words'] = data['cleaned_comment'].apply(lambda t: len(hazm.word_tokenize(t)))

# # # remove comments with the length of fewer than three words
data['cleaned_comment_len_by_words'] = data['cleaned_comment_len_by_words'].apply(lambda len_t: len_t if minlim < len_t <= maxlim else len_t)
data = data.dropna(subset=['cleaned_comment_len_by_words'])
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
data.head()
data['tweet_without_stopwords'] = data['cleaned_comment'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stopwords)]))
data = data[[1,'cleaned_comment']]
data.columns = ['label','comment']
data.head()

fig = go.Figure()

groupby_label = data.groupby('label')['label'].count()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=list(sorted(groupby_label.index)),
    y=groupby_label.tolist(),
    text=groupby_label.tolist(),
    textposition='auto'
))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Distribution of label within comments [DATA]',
    xaxis_title_text='Label',
    yaxis_title_text='Frequency',
    bargap=0.2,
    bargroupgap=0.2)

fig.show()


labels = list(sorted(data['label'].unique()))
label2id = {label: i for i, label in enumerate(labels)}
id2label = {v: k for k, v in label2id.items()}
print(f'label2id: {label2id}')
print(f'id2label: {id2label}')

data['label_id'] = data['label'].apply(lambda t: labels.index(t))
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.1, random_state=1, stratify=data['label'])
train, valid = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.1, random_state=1, stratify=train['label'])

train = train.reset_index(drop=True)
valid = valid.reset_index(drop=True)
test = test.reset_index(drop=True)

x_train, y_train = train['comment'].values.tolist(), train['label_id'].values.tolist()
x_valid, y_valid = valid['comment'].values.tolist(), valid['label_id'].values.tolist()
x_test, y_test = test['comment'].values.tolist(), test['label_id'].values.tolist()

print(train.shape)
print(valid.shape)
print(test.shape)

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH)
config = BertConfig.from_pretrained(
    MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH, **{
        'label2id': label2id,
        'id2label': id2label,
    })
print(config.to_json_string())
data
idx = np.random.randint(0, len(train))
sample_comment = train.iloc[idx]['comment']
sample_label = train.iloc[idx]['label']

print(f'Sample: \n{sample_comment}\n{sample_label}')

tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sample_comment)
token_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)

print(f'  Comment: {sample_comment}')
print(f'Token IDs: {token_ids}')
encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(
    sample_comment,
    max_length=32,
    truncation=True,
    add_special_tokens=True, # Add '[CLS]' and '[SEP]'
    return_token_type_ids=True,
    return_attention_mask=True,
    padding='max_length',
    return_tensors='pt',  # Return tensors
)

print(f'Keys: {encoding.keys()}\n')
for k in encoding.keys():
    print(f'{k}:\n{encoding[k]}')

class InputExample:
    """ A single example for simple sequence classification. """

    def __init__(self, guid, text_a, text_b=None, label=None):
        """ Constructs a InputExample. """
        self.guid = guid
        self.text_a = text_a
        self.text_b = text_b
        self.label = label


def make_examples(tokenizer, x, y=None, maxlen=128, output_mode="classification", is_tf_dataset=True):
    examples = []
    y = y if isinstance(y, list) or isinstance(y, np.ndarray) else [None] * len(x)

    for i, (_x, _y) in tqdm(enumerate(zip(x, y)), position=0, total=len(x)):
        guid = "%s" % i
        label = int(_y)
        
        if isinstance(_x, str):
            text_a = _x
            text_b = None
        else:
            assert len(_x) == 2
            text_a = _x[0]
            text_b = _x[1]
        
        examples.append(InputExample(guid=guid, text_a=text_a, text_b=text_b, label=label))
    
    features = glue_convert_examples_to_features(
        examples, 
        tokenizer, 
        maxlen, 
        output_mode=output_mode, 
        label_list=list(np.unique(y)))

    all_input_ids = []
    all_attention_masks = []
    all_token_type_ids = []
    all_labels = []

    for f in tqdm(features, position=0, total=len(examples)):
        if is_tf_dataset:
            all_input_ids.append(tf.constant(f.input_ids))
            all_attention_masks.append(tf.constant(f.attention_mask))
            all_token_type_ids.append(tf.constant(f.token_type_ids))
            all_labels.append(tf.constant(f.label))
        else:
            all_input_ids.append(f.input_ids)
            all_attention_masks.append(f.attention_mask)
            all_token_type_ids.append(f.token_type_ids)
            all_labels.append(f.label)

    if is_tf_dataset:
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({
            'input_ids': all_input_ids,
            'attention_mask': all_attention_masks,
            'token_type_ids': all_token_type_ids
        }, all_labels))

        return dataset, features
    
    xdata = [np.array(all_input_ids), np.array(all_attention_masks), np.array(all_token_type_ids)]
    ydata = all_labels

    return [xdata, ydata], features
    train_dataset_base, train_examples = make_examples(tokenizer, x_train, y_train, maxlen=128)
valid_dataset_base, valid_examples = make_examples(tokenizer, x_valid, y_valid, maxlen=128)

test_dataset_base, test_examples = make_examples(tokenizer, x_test, y_test, maxlen=128)
[xtest, ytest], test_examples = make_examples(tokenizer, x_test, y_test, maxlen=128, is_tf_dataset=False)
for value in train_dataset_base.take(1):
    print(f'     input_ids: {value[0]["input_ids"]}')
    print(f'        target: {value[1]}')
    def get_training_dataset(dataset, batch_size):
       dataset = dataset.repeat()
       dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048)
       dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    return dataset

def get_validation_dataset(dataset, batch_size):
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    return dataset

train_dataset = get_training_dataset(train_dataset_base, TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE)
valid_dataset = get_training_dataset(valid_dataset_base, VALID_BATCH_SIZE)

train_steps = len(train_examples) // TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE
valid_steps = len(valid_examples) // VALID_BATCH_SIZE

train_steps, valid_steps

def build_model(model_name, config, learning_rate=3e-5):
    model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, config=config)

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])

    return model
    r = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=valid_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
    validation_steps=valid_steps,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    verbose=1)

final_accuracy = r.history['val_accuracy']
print('FINAL ACCURACY MEAN: ', np.mean(final_accuracy))
model.save_pretrained(os.path.dirname(OUTPUT_PATH))
ev = model.evaluate(test_dataset_base.batch(TEST_BATCH_SIZE))
print()
print(f'Evaluation: {ev}')
print()

predictions = model.predict(xtest)
ypred = predictions[0].argmax(axis=-1).tolist()

print()
print(classification_report(ytest, ypred, target_names=labels))
print()

print(f'F1: {f1_score(ytest, ypred, average="weighted")}')


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-1b0a029a88ab> in <cell line: 175>()
    173 
    174 data['label_id'] = data['label'].apply(lambda t: labels.index(t))
--> 175 train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.1, random_state=1, stratify=data['label'])
    176 train, valid = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.1, random_state=1, stratify=train['label'])
    177 

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py

in _validate_shuffle_split(n_samples, test_size, train_size,
default_test_size)
2234
2235     if n_train == 0:
-> 2236         raise ValueError(
2237             "With n_samples={}, test_size={} and train_size={}, the "
2238             "resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the "
ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.1 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the

aforementioned parameters.

please help me to solve a error
dataset:

614484565059596288,"Dorian Gray with Rainbow Scarf",happy


Is cleantext.clean() a function you wrote or a library function you imported? The error message is clear and tells you exactly what the problem is - you are passing a keyword parameter that the function does not recognize.

cleantext is a library and clean is a function of this library."you are passing a keyword parameter that the function does not recognize"??? ok but I dont know how to solve this problem

I think you could simplify this example greatly by writing a 2 line script that imports cleantext and then does a simplified clean("test", fix_unicode=True). Part of writing a good question here on SO is to post a minimal script that shows the error - pull out all of the cruft.

As I can’t comment to ask for more information, I had to figure out some things by myself, although I am confident that my answer will resolve the problem.
You did not specify from where you installed the module, but by looking on the internet we can note that there are several python packages entitled cleantext.
What I believe happened, is that you found out about this package and decided to install it using a program (like pip). Although, you did not consider that the package spelled cleantext is actually not the same one. In this package, the function clean is defined as
def clean(text: str,  # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments, too-many-branches
          clean_all: bool = True,
          extra_spaces: bool = False,
          stemming: bool = False,
          stopwords: bool = False,
          lowercase: bool = False,
          numbers: bool = False,
          punct: bool = False,
          reg: str = '',
          reg_replace: str = '',
          stp_lang: str = 'english') -> str:

which does not have the arguments you were expecting. When python decodes your function call, it will realize that fix_unicode does not exists and will not continue the execution further, only raising an error about this specific argument.
To fix the issue, you should install the package named clean-text (with the hyphen). As you import both packages using the same name, I recommend you as well to uninstall the cleantext (without hyphen) package.
